# SoftAP to AP connection

Tags: wireless-networking, wireless-access-point, zeroconf

With the proliferation of connected devices, thanks to IoT and IoE, I see many devices supporting the concept of SoftAP. WeMo devices, being a case in point, which work by advertising a SoftAP like so, "WeMo.Insight.XXX" and once connected to this SoftAP, the WeMo app then displays the available APs.

I then have to select an AP that I want this WeMo device to connect to, enter the password for this network if it is not an open network and then I am connected to the AP.

I really am at loss in understanding the transition from SoftAP to AP. What really is the value of SoftAP when all it is doing is present the list of APs and that too only if I use the native WeMo app?

I'd understand the value of SoftAP if it allowed me to connect to the AP without having to enter the credentials manually and if I approved of sharing the AP credentials.

Any pointers would be greatly helpful.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A Wi-Fi-only (no Ethernet, Bluetooth, serial, etc.) device with no built-in screen or buttons has to come up in *some* mode so your PC or mobile device can connect to it to configure it.

It can't just read your mind and know exactly which network it should join or what the password is.

SoftAP mode is a great way to come up for that initial connection so it can be configured for its real connection.

Before device manufacturers were smart enough to use SoftAP mode, they'd use IBSS (ad hoc) mode, but that had its own problems; some IBSS clients would then propagate the IBSS network, which would cause more confusion.

Going forward, if Wi-Fi Direct catches on and enough PCs/Macs/smartphones/tablets support it, that might become the preferred way for devices without displays to get configured. But for now, it's not supported widely enough for device manufacturers to be able to depend on it. But connecting to APs has always been supported by everything for obvious reasons, so SoftAP mode is a safe bet.

Comment: Thank you, that was helpful and you bring up an interesting point about Wi-Fi Direct. My understanding is that Wi-Fi Direct uses SoftAP internally. Is that correct? Of course, I understand that at least one device should support Wi-Fi Direct before we can proceed.